# Notification for finished phpunit test in iTerm

Tags: macos, unit-testing, notifications, phpunit, iterm

I've got a few thousand unit tests in a project which I run with phpunit. Running them can take quite a while. I run them through and ant command though the Mac app iTerm. Is there some kind of toolchain with which I can be notified as soon as all tests run through?

Maybe something like a regex combined with local notifications over the notification center or as simple as a beep sound at the end of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is a pretty simple toolchain. iTerm supports "triggers" which you can set under Settings -> Profiles -> Advanced -> Triggers. You can use a regex there and use "Send Growl Alert" as action. In growl you can just pipe all notifications through to the notification center if you want to. Works for me.

**UPDATE**
Here a description for [Notifications with Growl](https://blog.liplex.de/show-notification-for-finished-phpunit-tests-in-iterm/)
Here a description for [Notifications with native OSX Notification Center](https://blog.liplex.de/native-osx-notifications-from-iterm-with-triggers/)